# Django creating order form model design

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on creating a model in which users can add items from a shopping cart, creating orders which are attached to the users. I'm wondering if I'm going about this the right way. It seems like a fairly common database design. Do I need a looser coupling with an Invoice table which would store a list of issues and then have the order be connect the Invoice number with User? I'm new to Django so any advice on a better modeling system would be appreciate.

Here is my model so far. Which works for the time being, but once the shopping cart feature is added it might not be as complex as it needs to be.

```
    REGION_CHOICES = (
    ('D', 'Domestic'),
    ('I', 'International')
)

class Source(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.source

class Role(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.role

class Subscriber(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    #is_international = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="hello")
    region = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=REGION_CHOICES)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Issue(models.Model):
    Volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.Volume)

class Order(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber)
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.subscriber)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid approach is to get your app working with the minimum set of fields and then go adding new ones when the need arises.

With [django 1.7, migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) are native and easy to use. You can add tables and relationships easily later as long as you are using the system the right way.